# How to call a C# method only if it exists?

Tags: c#

Is this possible without reflection otherwise with reflection ? This is something very often used in PHP like in Wordpress.

Something in pseudo code:

```
if (exists(object.method)) {object.method}
```

or

```
try {object.method} finally {...}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "only if it exists?"

Comment: Even with reflection, you would have to take the method's prototype into account: `int Foo(string bar)` is not the same as `double Foo(int bar, IDictionary<int, string> quux)`.

Comment: Are you looking for partial methods? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6b0scde8.aspx

Comment: Check for null your MethodInfo object

Comment: @Ani yeah I think partial method is the elegant solution, will check if it really works...

Comment: Weird no answer mentioned partial method ?

Comment: @user310291: No, because partial methods don't really help here IMO unless you're calling the method *from the same class* (and you don't need any return values). Of course, it doesn't help that you've given us basically no information as to why you need this.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm even with null-propagating operator you would have gotten a compile time error. All the provided answers still hold true to today. So I find the out-of-date statement to not hold merit

Comment: @Nkosi Using a null-propagating operator could have made Skeet's answer more concise, AFAIK.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Agreed, but how does that relate to `calling a method only if it exists`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could use dynamics and catch the Runtime exception:

```
dynamic d = 5;
try
{
    Console.WriteLine(d.FakeMethod(4));
}
catch(RuntimeBinderException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Method doesn't exist");
}
```

Although it sounds more like a design problem.

**Disclaimer**
This code is not for use, just an example that it can be done.

Comment: Using exceptions for flow control is nasty, Nasty, NASTY.

Comment: As Jason says, this will be nasty - and the performance hit could be pretty big as well, if you're doing this a lot.

Comment: @user310291: Yeah, it's what you want in the same way that your physician solving your carpal tunnel syndrome by chopping your arms off is what you want.

Comment: If you guys think the educational purpose of this code isn't worth seeing it in someone's code, I can delete it.

Comment: I don't care about the nastiness it's only for functional demo not for real deployment.

Comment: This is why I'm always so critical of SO. You answer a question as-written and you get nothing but griping and moaning in response. In a good many cases, there is NOTHING wrong with this code.

Not everything is RT code for the space shuttle. Oftentimes, things take a second or three and it's FINE.

Answer (score 23):

Well, you could declare it in an interface, and then use:

```
IFoo foo = bar as IFoo;
if (foo != null)
{
    foo.MethodInInterface();
}
```

That assumes you can make the object's actual type implement the interface though.

Otherwise you'd need to use reflection AFAIK.

(EDIT: The dynamic typing mentioned elsewhere would work on .NET 4 too, of course... but catching an exception for this is pretty nasty IMO.)

Comment: A possible performance optimization if this isn't possible would be to use reflection once, and generate a dynamic method to optimize future calls.

Comment: Too heavy in the context I want to use: it's about for 50 methods if I had to create an interface for each single method ...

Comment: This would be the .net way of doing this.  The reflection answer is also a reasonable way of doing this, but carries a significant performance hit compared to using an Interface.   PHP does allow dynamic methods like this, but I agree with user166390, this falls in the category of trying to shoehorn a feature of a different language into another.   The dynamic method also "works" but I would agree, this seems very kludgy and would carry a performance hit as well.

Answer (score 14):

Use `.GetType().GetMethod()` to check if it exists, and then `.Invoke()` it.

```
var fooBar = new FooBarClass();
var method = fooBar.GetType().GetMethod("ExistingOrNonExistingMethod");
if (method != null)
{
    method.Invoke(fooBar, new object[0]);
}
```

Comment: I would personally use this example if I wanted to either avoid dynamic, or I didn't maintain the source of `FooBarClass` and knew it could change in the future to no longer include the method I am looking for.

Answer (score 6):

With the `dynamic` type in C# 4.0, you *could* do something like this:

```
dynamic obj = GetDynamicObject();
if (obj != null && obj.GetType().GetMethod("DoSomething") != null)
{
    obj.DoSomething();
}
```

But the only way to tell if a type has a method in the first place is to use reflection; so the above approach doesn't really buy you anything (you might as well take the `MethodInfo` you get from calling `GetMethod` and just `Invoke` it).

**Edit**: If you're open to trying to call the method even when it's not there, then [Yuriy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856644/how-to-call-a-c-method-only-if-it-exists/4856685#4856685) is probably what you're looking for. My original answer was a literal response to the way you worded your question: "How to call a C# method **only if it exists**."

Answer (score 3):

I came across this looking for the same answer but did not like any of the solutions.

here is mine:

```
//Invoke the refresh method if the datasource contains it
if (this.DataSource.GetType().GetMethod("Refresh") != null)
     this.DataSource.GetType().GetMethod("Refresh").Invoke(this.DataSource, new object[] { });
```

Answer (score 2):

You should revise existance first.  `MethodInfo[] myArrayMethodInfo = myType.GetMethods();`